# Is it possible to install static libraries from apt in 18.04 x86_64?

Tags: 18.04, compiling, libraries, static-linking

I'm trying to build a project that depends on binary distributed static libraries.

The linker complains it cannot find `ini_config` functions, among others:

```
config_params.c:(.text+0x16f): undefined reference to  `ini_get_config_valueobj'
```

It finds the dynamic libraries, but not the static version:

```
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libini_config.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libini_config.so succeeded
```

Those files are present on debian stretch. Is there a way to get them on ubuntu as well ?

Comment: Those are also available on Ubuntu: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libini_config.a

Comment: The location is different there `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libini_config.a` than where it is looking... you will probably need to make sure `libini-config-dev` is installed and then include `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` when compiling.

Comment: Yes, there it is! Thank you, I've missed that. But the linker is looking into `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/` and finds the `.so`, how can I change that?

Comment: So, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578484/telling-gcc-directly-to-link-a-library-statically), I just need to replace `-ldl` with `-l:libdl.a`.

Answer (score 4):

All packages seem to install their static libraries. They can be found in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Apparently, the linker first picks the dynamic libraries when using `-lsomelib`. To override that, you can use the `-l:libsomelib.a`, it will then only match the exact filename `somelib.a`. Use `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` the same way as for "linking" dynamic libraries.

To debug the library searching phase, you can add `-Wl`, `--verbose` to your `LDFLAGS`. `gcc` will then display every path it tries for your `-lXXX` options.

Keep in mind that archives are checked only once, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44164350/2686218), if some symbols are still not found, you maybe have to reorder the parameters.